# Spring MVC - accessing a static page through Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot web application, using embedded Tomcat + Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used :

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE,
Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE,
Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE,
Tomcat Embed 8.5.6,
Maven 3,
Java 8

I want to access an static file located in `../src/main/resources/templates/mockups/index.html`

so I created this controller:

```
@Controller
public class MockupIndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/mockup/index")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "/mockups/index.html";
    }

}
```

but I got this error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/mockups/index.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring xml configuration file, map your static files location, please keep static files in different folder

```
 <mvc:resources mapping = "/mockups/**" location = "/src/main/resources/templates/mockups/" />
```

Changes this line

```
 return "/mockups/index.html";
```

to

```
 return "redirect:/mockups/index.html";
```

If you are not using config file then add this class

```
@Component
class WebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/mockups/**").addResourceLocations("/src/main/resources/templates/mockups/");
   }
}
```

Comment: i am not using xml configuration files